# AngularJS ng-change alternative for using select2

Tags: javascript, angularjs

ng-change doesn't seem to be working with select2. Is there a limitation like this and is there any alternative?

```
<select ng-change = "selected()" ng-model = "sel" > 
    <option value=""></option>
    <option ng-repeat = "o in range" value="{{o.value}}">{{ o.value }}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you using ui-select2?

Comment: Have you looked into using ng-options? This might help. Also, how do you know ng-change isn't getting called? Maybe it just doesn't do what you think!

Comment: ng-options is not compatible with select2.
All I am trying to do on ng-change is set a value.

Comment: What about using $scope.$watch on 'sel'?

Comment: Tried but couldn't make it work 
    **$scope.selected = function(){
        //selected value
    }
    $scope.$watch('sel', $scope.selected(), true);**